# How to apply a function to values in a stream produced by streaming library

Tags: haskell, streaming

I'm producing a stream of `Just` values using the `streaming` library, but I'm having a problem transforming the stream using a simple function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack

import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
import Data.Maybe

stream :: Stream (Of (Maybe Integer)) Maybe ()
stream = S.each [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3, Just 4, Just 5]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ S.mapM (\x -> isJust x) stream
  print "done"
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
test.hs:13:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe b0’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • In the expression: isJust x
      In the first argument of ‘S.mapM’, namely ‘(\ x -> isJust x)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘S.mapM (\ x -> isJust x) stream’
   |
13 |   print $ S.mapM (\x -> isJust x) stream
   |                         ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Remember that `\x -> isJust x` is equivalent to simply writing `isJust`.

Answer (score 3):

`Streaming.Prelude.mapM` has type

```
Monad m => (a -> m b) -> Stream (Of a) m r -> Stream (Of b) m
```

which is why the typechecker expects the function's return type to be `Maybe b0`.

What you need here is

```
Streaming.Prelude.map :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> Stream (Of a) m r -> Stream (Of b) m r
```

or simply

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```